# Using function to return key for object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I was wondering if I can render random number by assigning function inside of object key. But it rather renders the whole function as a string value. Would there be an alternate way to do the same thing I'm trying to do?

```
let listings = [
    {
        content1: 'Content #1',
        content2: 'Content #2',
        content3: function(){
            return Math.random()
        } 
    },
    {
        content1: 'Content #1_1',
        content2: 'Content #2_1',
        content3: function(){
            return Math.random()
        }
    }
];

console.log(listings[0].content3);        //output: f(){ return Math.random() }
console.log(typeof listings[0].content3); //output: function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't trigger the function, you only need to do this

```
console.log(listings[0].content3());
```